# How I can run .exe file with monodevelop, without running it through compiler?

Tags: 16.04, steam, mono, monodevelop

So I have monodevelop. 
I can run .exe file (in my case PC steam guard authenticator)
How I can run it without going to program itself? 
Can I somehow 'emulate' it?

[image: popups]

I just want to get rid of that 'Run debugging' thing...
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the *.exe* file in your project directory and run it as needed.
What I mean as needed if it is a GUI project then open as normal *.exe*, but if you need to see the command line you want to open with mono runtime (terminal).